Is it possible to download installed app from Samsung SmartTV (TizenOS)?
I have one old Samsung SmartTV (with TizenOS on it) and installed app (widget) from SmartHub store
Now I have new one TV and want to have that app installed on it. But, that app was removed from official store...
It is possible to download already installed app from old TV and reinstall it on new one? (if I can obtain wgt package file, I think, it is possible to install it with Tizen Studio on the new TV)
Tried to search the web for wgt package for this app, but have no luck...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

it is impossible due to lack of access with root rights (blocked by the manufacturer)
